# How to get multiple nodes by single request?

Tags: javascript, gun

*gun 0.8.8*

Is it possible to get multiple nodes by single get request?

For example, something like this

```
gun.mget([ "nodeNameA", "nodeNameB" ], function(value) 
  console.log(value);
  /*
    {
      "nodeNameA": { my: "Special", variable: 123 },
      "nodeNameB": { the: "Glory", answer: 42 }
    }
  */
  // ... do something ...
});
```

In many databases, you can get multiple objects by a single query. Due to the network latency sometimes it is faster to get a single response instead of hundreds of small ones.

Comment: not really but you could easily write a function for that... It all really depends on the chaining logic you want to achieve.

Comment: @Salketer do you mean a function which produces multiple requests? Definitely, it can be done. What I want is a single request which gives me all nodes by their names.

Comment: Please update your question with what you are trying to achieve... Why is the single request a must? Are you trying to save roundtrips, trying to simplify async callback nesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@trex ,

Using the extended API `.open(cb)` on a table is probably what you want.

Here is an example:

```
var gun = Gun();

gun.get('nodeNameA').put({ my: "Special", variable: 123 });
gun.get('table').set(gun.get('nodeNameA'));


gun.get('nodeNameB').put({ the: "Glory", answer: 42 });
gun.get('table').set(gun.get('nodeNameB'));


gun.get('table').open(function(data, key){
  console.log("update:", data);
  /*
    {
      "nodeNameA": { my: "Special", variable: 123 },
      "nodeNameB": { the: "Glory", answer: 42 }
    }
  */
});
```

Play with it yourself here: http://jsbin.com/ditohivovo/edit?js,console !

**Documentation** is available here:

https://github.com/amark/gun/wiki/API#open

> Note: You must include it with `require('lib/open.js')` or `<script src="gun/lib/open.js"></script>` in the browser.